# Is there a more Pythonic way to combine an Else: statement and an Except:?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a piece of code that searches AutoCAD for text boxes that contain certain keywords (eg. `"overall_weight"` in this case) and replaces it with a value from a dictionary. However, sometimes the dictionary key is assigned to an empty string and sometimes, the key doesn't exist altogether. In these cases, the `"overall_weight"` keywords should be replaced with `"N/A"`. I was wondering if there was a more pythonic way to combine the `KeyError` exception and the `else` to both go to `nObject.TextString = "N/A"` so its not typed twice.

```
if nObject.TextString == "overall_weight":
    try:
        if self.var.jobDetails["Overall Weight"]:
            nObject.TextString = self.var.jobDetails["Overall Weight"]
        else:
            nObject.TextString = "N/A"
    except KeyError:
        nObject.TextString = "N/A"
```

Edit: For clarification for future visitors, there are only 3 cases I need to take care of and the correct answer takes care of all 3 cases without any extra padding.

1. `dict[key]` exists and points to a non-empty string. `TextString` replaced with the value assigned to `dict[key]`.
2. `dict[key]` exists and points to a empty string. `TextString` replaced with `"N/A"`.
3. `dict[key]` doesn't exist. `TextString` replaced with `"N/A"`.

Comment: By *dictionary key is empty*, you mean an empty string or `None`?

Comment: You could put a raise in the else to prevent some repetition

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, I mean an empty string. I edited the question.

Comment: You should not rely on KeyError if you want to know whether key is in the dictionary: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/332218/does-pythons-defaultdict-violate-the-lsp/332221#332221

Comment: @VadimPushtaev That depends on the context. The `defaultdict` is *precisely* intended in the case where "key not found" **can** be handled by just inserting it on the fly with a default value. In other words: it is meant to replace python code that would call the `setdefault` method everytime it accesses the elements of the dictionary. If "key not found" should be handled differently, sure, you have to use `if key in my_dict` etc.

Comment: This belongs on Code Review SE.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `fields` in the text blocks? Assuming you control the .dwg and have a licensed Autodesk program, you can set properties for drawings (or projects/sheetsets that refer to multiple drawings) and just let native functionality perform the string substitution for you.

Comment: @brichins Not sure what you mean. Do you mean that there's an attribute for the textboxes called `fields` in the AutoCAD COM? Do you mean the `fields` within AutoCAD itself? I'm not the one who designed the templates, and there are already hundreds of them, and each of them has up to 70 or 80 textboxes, some single line and some multiline.

Comment: I meant AutoCAD fields inside the textbox values. Great for organized projects and files, admittedly less useful for existing projects. If this is something you have to do [often enough](https://xkcd.com/1205/) (these are *templates*?), you might consider investing up front in getting organized and programmaticly replacing the text with fields instead of the actual values, then setting up the document/project properties. Take yourself out of the loop and let whoever's using the .dwgs configure them - win-win.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use `dict.get()` which will return the value associated with the given key if it exists otherwise `None`. (Note that `''` and `None` are both falsey values.) If `s` is true then assign it to `nObject.TextString` otherwise give it a value of `"N/A"`.

```
if nObject.TextString == "overall_weight":
    nObject.TextString = self.var.jobDetails.get("Overall Weight") or "N/A"
```

Comment: Now, this is brilliant

Comment: LOL - looks like your comment to me was based on the same thinking! Just ditch the other if's.

Comment: @tdelaney I wrote the comment to you and then I decided to just make my own answer.

Comment: But what if the key returns a 0 ? Is 0 a valid "N/A" assignment?

Comment: I think this answer is "too clever" personally.

Comment: @MooingRawr That's unspecified by the OP, but is a potential problem. Presumably, however, all of the values in the dictionary are of the same type (i.e. `str`) as that is just good practice in general and the variable that we are assigning to is a `TextString`.

Comment: I do like this answer, as I use or and ? (in C#) all the time, but I've been burned by it before... Just want to make sure it's not going to cause sleepless nights :\

Comment: @pzp All the values in the dictionary are strings, so if the `key` returns a 0, I would like the `nObject.TextString` to display 0. This is perfect, thanks.

Comment: @pzp it's not a compliment. Code should be straightforward and avoid "clever" tricks that can be easily missed or cause confusion when someone reads the code in the future.

Comment: @rlbond what do you mean too clever? it's clear and efficient, the intent is obvious at first read.

Comment: @njzk2 I suppose it's non-obvious that you explicitly want `''` to be substituted as `'N/A'`. Someone reading the code later might think that is a bug.

Comment: @Bob You're expecting someone to modify the code later on and yet you don't have unit tests to validate correctness for such corner cases?

Comment: @Bob that's what the OP's code `if self.var.jobDetails["Overall Weight"]:` does. it tests for the truthness of the value. but I guess mixing strings with boolean operators can be confusing at first.

Answer (score 17):

Use `get()` function for dictionaries. It will return `None` if the key doesn't exist or if you specify a second value, it will set that as the default. Then your syntax will look like:

```
nObject.TextString = self.var.jobDetails.get('Overall Weight', 'N/A')
```

Comment: This does not handle the case where *the dictionary key is empty* i.e value is an empty string

Comment: What difference does it make if there are empty *keys* in the dict?

Comment: @pzp `self.var.jobDetails["Overall Weight"]` could raise a `KeyError`.

Comment: @pzp `nObject.TextString` gets assigned to an empty string which is not what the OP wants

Comment: No, the OP said that the key can be an empty string but did not mention anything about the values.

Comment: @pzp Read the comments on the question

Comment: Sorry. For clarification, its not the keys themselves that are empty strings, but the values the key points to. So there are 2 cases I need to cover. No key at all, and key that points to empty string. Both these cases need to become "N/A"

Comment: Couldn't you just fix this with just an else statement?`if dict.get(key): nObject.TextString = self.var.jobDetails["Overall Weight"] else: nObject.TextString = "N/A"` Would handle if the key was None or empty string.

Comment: see also the `setdefault` method, which is similar but inserts the default value too.

Comment: @MooingRawr That has the same potential problem as my answer, i.e. that it fails if `0` (the `int`, not to be confused with `'0'`) is a value.

Comment: @pzp I realized that as I was reading your answer. But OP doesn't give enough detail to the question, we can only hope, dream and pray.

Comment: @MooingRawr, there are only 3 cases. One, the dictionary key points to a regular string. `nObject.TextString` is replaced with the key string. Two, the key points to an empty string. `nObject.TextString` should be replaced with `"N/A"`. Three, the key doesn't exist. `nObject.TextString` should be replaced with `"N/A"`.

Comment: @RBuntu so the key will never return a integer 0. Okie then.

Answer (score 9):

Use `.get()` with a default argument of `"N/A"` which will be used if the key does not exist:

```
nObject.TextString = self.var.jobDetails.get("Overall Weight", "N/A")
```

## Update

If empty strings need to be handled, simply modify as follows:

```
nObject.TextString = self.var.jobDetails.get("Overall Weight") or "N/A"
```

This will set `nObject.TextString` to "N/A" if a `KeyError` is raised, or if the value is retrieved is empty: `''`, `[]`, etc.

Comment: This doesn't cover the case where `self.var.jobDetails["Overall Weight"]` raises a `KeyError`.

Comment: This does not handle the case where *the dictionary key is empty* i.e value is an empty string

Comment: @tdelaney it does: with `get()` if a `KeyError` is raised, the default `"N/A"` will be returned. Try the following: `{'a':1}.get('b', "N/A")`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye thanks for pointing this out. I did not realize that the value could be an empty string, and have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a good case for setting the default value in advance

```
if nObject.TextString == "overall_weight":
    nObject.TextString = "N/A"
    try:
        if self.var.jobDetails["Overall Weight"]:
            nObject.TextString = self.var.jobDetails["Overall Weight"]
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

**RADICAL RETHINK**

Ditch that first answer (just keeping it because it got an upvote). If you really want to go pythonic, (and you always want to set a value on TextString) replace the whole thing with

```
nObject.TextString = (nObject.TextString == "overall_weight"
    and self.var.jobDetails.get("Overall Weight")
    or "N/A")
```

Python `and` and `or` operations return their last calculated value, not True/False and you can use that to walk through the combinations.

Comment: @pzp Good point and I realized there is a more radical way to solve the problem.

Comment: The line repeat in the radical answer isn't needed, and surely it would overwrite all values that are not `overall_weight` with `N/A`?

Comment: surely you don't need 2 `and self.var.jobDetails.get("Overall Weight")`?

Comment: This answer's "RADICAL RETHINK" changes the text to N/A even if it didn't contain `overall_weight`, which will replace all the textboxes no matter what. If OP uses this it will mess up his program. Please fix with an `if`

Answer (score 2):

The Zen of Python says "Explicit is better than implicit." I have found this to be very true in my own experience. When I write a piece of code I think to my self, "Will I understand what this means a year from now?" If the answer is "no" then it needs to be re-written or documented. The accepted answer relies on remembering the implementation of dict.get to know how it will handle the corner cases. Since the OP has 3 clear criteria, I would instead document them clearly in an if statement.

```
if nObject.TextString == "overall_weight" and \
    "Overall Weight" in self.var.jobDetails and \
    self.var.jobDetails["Overall Weight"] != "":
    nObject.TextString = self.var.jobDetails["Overall Weight"]
else:
    nObject.TextString = "N/A"
```

It's certainly more verbose... but that's a good thing. There is no question when reading this what the behavior will be.

Answer (score -2):

How about [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

```
key = 'Overall Weight'

with n_object.text_string = self.var.job_details[key]:
    if self.var.job_details[key] is None \
    or if self.var.job_details[key] is '' \
    or if KeyError:
        n_object.text_string = 'N/A'
```

Comment: `key is None`? in what situation would you expect that to be true?

Comment: @njzk2 My mistake. I have changed it to value.

Comment: `if KeyError` ? what do you expect that to do ?